# How to only take 1 value out of a response in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, formatting, response

Hello so i got this result for example:

{'captchaId': '67561984031', 'code': '03AGdBq26D5XwT-p6LuAwftuZ3gUcvj0dB7lhZUT7OOfKIZU_wZzN03CCVZAaRGzzD0rXVbsJOjTBN1Ed2d0v0X6Tl2wQQPbT_R1lRHOkh5FFU46MN3tfVbajIFyZfZHUHZAt_h-5yY0cVqfJTy1_fwebyr-ilN_N1R04214z9WVXg9-cuSYJD9a2cpDNknXhvVjLxIfmVGgW9dJlouGCxZ0QbJxodRNUkQBXQTLr7DI1h-uJINlVzKvq4XguuChbQ0k2s1PrbEQK_Ir15-cAfPmldrJT5gEfjFAyBedn2Syum6axx_PRhVouXHpSKpx7-65Cw1FeBiUZ-IUSt_-E2i8NgUBXYpGt9nMIglKSSiFfO0nLcbOJuwbOObt5LvCPgfPhy2Uss9yz19F-e6GlGUuFgc7dODLN91fKUXCEmW9XG_FonSd2XV3k'}

and i only need the value thats in the "code", so only "03AGdBq...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided any code so, I may not give you exact answer but you can try this:

```
st={'captchaId': '67561984031', 'code': '03AGdBq26D5XwT-p6LuAwftuZ3gUcvj0dB7lhZUT7OOfKIZU_wZzN03CCVZAaRGzzD0rXVbsJOjTBN1Ed2d0v0X6Tl2wQQPbT_R1lRHOkh5FFU46MN3tfVbajIFyZfZHUHZAt_h-5yY0cVqfJTy1_fwebyr-ilN_N1R04214z9WVXg9-cuSYJD9a2cpDNknXhvVjLxIfmVGgW9dJlouGCxZ0QbJxodRNUkQBXQTLr7DI1h-uJINlVzKvq4XguuChbQ0k2s1PrbEQK_Ir15-cAfPmldrJT5gEfjFAyBedn2Syum6axx_PRhVouXHpSKpx7-65Cw1FeBiUZ-IUSt_-E2i8NgUBXYpGt9nMIglKSSiFfO0nLcbOJuwbOObt5LvCPgfPhy2Uss9yz19F-e6GlGUuFgc7dODLN91fKUXCEmW9XG_FonSd2XV3k'}
st=dict(st)
print(st["code"])
```

And if it is response from `requests` then you may do this:

```
response=requests.get()
response=response.json()
#or response=requests.get().json()
print(response["code"])
```

Comment: the last  part with the "print(response["code"])" was enough to do the trick, thank you!

Comment: Mark this as accepted  answer and if you like it give upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a dictionary, so you can just access the terms like you would in a dictionary.
eg.

```py
dict = {
        'firstkey': 'firstvalue',
        'secondkey': 'secondvalue'
       }
```

so if you call `dict[firstkey]`, it would return `firstvalue`. 
In your case, you can just save that into `var` and access it through `var[code]`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library for python.  If you are reading the response from a file you can do something like:

```
import json

with open("/tmp/test.json", "r") as src_json:
        src=json.load(src_json)
        print(src["code"])
```